# Django get_model() causing Error: cannot import name settings

Tags: django, import, settings, importerror

**Update:**

I've tried modifying `from actstream import settings as actstream_settings` to `import actstream.settings as actstream_settings` and it's telling me:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'settings'
```

The `__init__.py` file in the `actstream` app is not empty, could this be why it cannot import `actstream/settings.py` as `actstream.settings`?

**Original Problem:**

I have a working django project.  I installed the following app `actstream` from trunk since the most recent release has errors: https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream

When loading this app into my project it throws the following exception:

```
Error: cannot import name settings
```

I have verified that the error occurs from the first command `get_model()` from `actstream/settings.py`, which looks like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models import get_model
import sys

MODELS = {}
for model in getattr(settings, 'ACTSTREAM_ACTION_MODELS', ('auth.User',)):
    MODELS[model.lower()] = model = get_model(*model.split('.'))

MANAGER_MODULE = getattr(settings, 'ACTSTREAM_MANAGER',
    'actstream.managers.ActionManager')
a, j = MANAGER_MODULE.split('.'), lambda l: '.'.join(l)
MANAGER_MODULE = getattr(__import__(j(a[:-1]), {}, {}, [a[-1]]), a[-1])

USE_JSONFIELD = getattr(settings, 'ACTSTREAM_USE_JSONFIELD', False)
```

Why would `get_model()` be throwing an error about being unable to load `settings` in this instance?

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../actstream/settings.py", line 7, in <module>
    MODELS[model.lower()] = model = get_model(*model.split('.'))
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 213, in get_model
    self._populate()
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 67, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File ".../libs/actstream/models.py", line 12, in <module>
    from actstream import managers, settings as actstream_settings
ImportError: cannot import name settings
```

I now notice that the import error is happening in models.py, but I still don't see how it cannot import the settings.py file as actstream.settings.

Comment: Please can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Added the traceback.  I don't understand how that import statement is failing though.

Comment: This seems caused by a circular import.  `settings.py` importing `models.py` through the get_model() function further importing `settings.py` again.  Ticket to author issued here: https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/issues/102